# Stateless static methods vs. C functions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, static-methods

In terms of good Objective-C coding practices, if I create a function that has no state, is it better to write it as a static method of some class or as a C function?

For example, I have a special filepath retrieval method that checks the Caches directory before proceeding to the main NSBundle. I currently have it as a static method under an otherwise empty Utils class. Should this be a C function instead?

The reason I've chosen to use a static method (for now) is that a) it's consistent with Objective-C syntax, and b) the class helps to categorize the method. However, I feel like I'm cheating a little, since I could easily fill up my Util class with these stateless static methods and end up with an ugly "shell class", whose sole purpose would be to hold them.

What convention do you use? Is one "better" than the other, by some objective metric? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you can think of an *existing* class of which this might make a good method, you can inject your method into it by making an Objective-C category. This keeps your two reasons for using a static method while not polluting the class space with an extra class.

For example:

```
@interface NSString (MyStringCategories) 
- (NSString*) myCoolMethod;
@end

// [StringCategories.m]
#import "StringCategories.h"

@implementation NSString (MyStringCategories)
- (NSString*) myCoolMethod {
    // do cool stuff here
    return whateverYouLike;
}
@end
```

Now you can send `myCoolMethod` to *any* string. Cool!

In your particular case, it sounds like a method on NSBundle might be an appropriate architecture. And don't forget, it can be a class method, so you don't need to instantiate anything in order to call your method.

Comment: Yes, I try to do that as often as possible. Couldn't think of one in this case, though -- it only searches the bundle if it doesn't find the file in Caches, and it's not an instance method like the typical pathForResource:, so (in my opinion) it's not an ideal fit.

Comment: So make it a class method. My point is, isn't the inability to think of an appropriate existing class just a failure of the imagination? It could be NSBundle, it could be NSFileManager, it could be NSString (because it deals with pathnames), it could be any class _you_ intuitively feel is in the right ballpark.

Comment: +1 For the category. I personally think the purpose of a class is to be instanciated. Don't use a class as a namespace. So if you only have static methods, you should consider another approach.

Comment: @Macmade - Apple thinks you're wrong, though. In one of the WWDC 2011 videos they talk about using class methods as a way to *avoid* having to make a shared instance, for example. And of course there are *lots* of built-in class methods, such as UIFont's `familyNames`, that are really just global functions, as it were, that have been placed into an appropriate class just as a way to, uh, classify them. To miss class methods is to miss part of the spirit of OOP.

Comment: @matt I guess Apple thinks a lot of things... IMHO, a singleton is even better that a 'static' class. UIFont is not a good example, as a UIFont object can be (and need to be) instanciated, as it needs iVars. Static methods, in such a case, are helpful, because they provide convenience constructor, of helper methods. But at the end, you have a real instance of UIFont. That's not the case in the question asked here.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a difficult question to answer because for a lot of people the answer will depend on what their personal preferences and tastes are. I personally think that if you have a function that is a function, i.e. it has nothing to do with an object, it has no internal state etc. pp. please let it be a function and do not try to wrap everything you possibly can into an object just because you are using an OO language and you can.

In order to keep my answer short let me refer to a (imo) quite good book:

http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm

I know that this is for C++, but there are quite a few insights that can be shared with other languages (esp. Objective-C and Objective-C++) especially from the part called "Class Design and Inheritance". There you will find an item titeled "Prefer writing nonmember nonfriend functions".

Bottom line: "Nonmember nonfriend functions *improve* encapsulation by minimizing dependencies[...] They also break apart monolithic classes[...] [and] improve genericity[...]".

I think there is quite some truth in that item.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no class to clearly bind it to, then I use a function. I also use functions for these utility bits because they can be stripped if not used or referenced. In that regard, it's also helpful to use a function because a link error is better than a runtime error (in the even the .m was accidentally omitted from the build, or if was referenced from another externally updated method). One problem with ObjC symbols is that they do not get stripped, so they naturally carry a high amount of dependency -- all the objc methods and classes, and required category methods must exist in the final binary. That's not an issue with really small programs or libraries, but it quickly gains weight with medium/large systems and libraries.

Everything does not need to be declared in an `@interface` - especially with larger systems where all those declarations will really turn your interdependencies into spaghetti. Compared to methods, functions are faster, smaller, may be optimized better by the compiler or during linking, and may be stripped if not referenced.

If you need polymorphism, it just belongs in a class for organization or convenience, then a class or instance method is often a better choice.

I also minimize declaring category methods for the same reasons. When you're using functions, you can easily write a wrapper method where you need it and get the best of both worlds.